# How to print like printf in Python3?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

In Python 2 I used:

```
print "a=%d,b=%d" % (f(x,n),g(x,n))
```

I've tried:

```
print("a=%d,b=%d") % (f(x,n),g(x,n))
```

Comment: `%` has always been a string operator, not related to the `print` statement. You could, for example, create a string with `s="a=%d,b=%d"%(f(x,n),g(x,n))`, then print that string with `print s`.

Answer (score 262, accepted):

In Python2, `print` was a keyword which introduced a statement:

```
print "Hi"
```

In Python3, `print` is a function which may be invoked:

```
print ("Hi")
```

In both versions, `%` is an operator which requires a string on the left-hand side and a value or a tuple of values or a mapping object (like `dict`) on the right-hand side.

So, your line ought to look like this:

```
print("a=%d,b=%d" % (f(x,n),g(x,n)))
```

Also, the recommendation for Python3 and newer is to use `{}`-style formatting instead of `%`-style formatting:

```
print('a={:d}, b={:d}'.format(f(x,n),g(x,n)))
```

Python 3.6 introduces yet another string-formatting paradigm: [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings).

```
print(f'a={f(x,n):d}, b={g(x,n):d}')
```

Comment: *or:*

    `print('a={first:4.2f}, b={second:03d}'.format(first=f(x,n),second=g(x,n)))`

where this example shows how you can use the printf-style modifiers *and* still use keywords.

Comment: @rapt, it has some huge advantages. Not the least of which is you can reference the same format only multiple times or out of order: "{1}, {1}, {0}, and {1} ".format("eggs","spam")=="spam, spam, eggs, and spam"

Comment: `%` allows replacements to be specified by a mapping, which accommodates out-of-order replacement; but for some reason that eludes me, you can't use a key more than once. `'%{x)s %(y)s' % {'y': 'bar', 'x': 'foo'}`, but not `'%{x)s %(y)s %(x)s' % {'y': 'bar', 'x': 'foo'}`.

Answer (score 68):

The most recommended way to do is to use `format` method. Read more about it [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax)

```
a, b = 1, 2

print("a={0},b={1}".format(a, b))
```

Answer (score 47):

Simple printf() function from [O'Reilly's Python Cookbook](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/python-cookbook/0596001673/).

```
import sys
def printf(format, *args):
    sys.stdout.write(format % args)
```

Example output:

```
i = 7
pi = 3.14159265359
printf("hi there, i=%d, pi=%.2f\n", i, pi)
# hi there, i=7, pi=3.14
```

Comment: Heh...  `PRINT` and `FORMAT`...?  Back in time 60+ years to the days of FORTRAN :)

Answer (score 34):

Python 3.6 introduced f-strings for inline interpolation. What's even nicer is it extended the syntax to also allow format specifiers with interpolation. Something I've been working on while I googled this (and came across this old question!):

```
print(f'{account:40s} ({ratio:3.2f}) -> AUD {splitAmount}')
```

[PEP 498](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/) has the details. And... it sorted my pet peeve with format specifiers in other langs -- allows for specifiers that themselves can be expressions! Yay! See: [Format Specifiers](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/#format-specifiers).

Comment: Note: This is also the most performant way to inject variables into strings.

Comment: Because python2 phased out, this should be best answer.

Answer (score 18):

Simple Example:

`print("foo %d, bar %d" % (1,2))`

Answer (score 11):

A simpler one.

```
def printf(format, *values):
    print(format % values )
```

Then:

```
printf("Hello, this is my name %s and my age %d", "Martin", 20)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
print("Name={}, balance={}".format(var-name, var-balance))
```

Answer (score 3):

You can literally use `printf` in Python through the `ctypes` module (or even your own C extension module).

On **Linux**, you should be able to do

```
import ctypes

libc = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary("libc.so.6")
printf = libc.printf
printf(b"Integer: %d\n"
       b"String : %s\n"
       b"Double : %f (%%f style)\n"
       b"Double : %g      (%%g style)\n",
       42, b"some string", ctypes.c_double(3.20), ctypes.c_double(3.20))
```

On **Windows**, the equivalent would have

```
libc = ctypes.cdll.msvcrt
printf = libc.printf
```

As stated in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#calling-functions):

> None, integers, bytes objects and (unicode) strings are the only native Python objects that can directly be used as parameters in these function calls. None is passed as a C NULL pointer, bytes objects and strings are passed as pointer to the memory block that contains their data (char* or wchar_t*). Python integers are passed as the platforms default C int type, their value is masked to fit into the C type.

This explains why I wrapped the Python float objects using `ctypes.c_double` (FYI, a Python `float` is typically a `double` in C).

**Output**

```
Integer: 42
String : some string
Double : 3.200000 (%f style)
Double : 3.2      (%g style)
```

Answer (score 2):

Because your `%` is outside the `print(...)` parentheses, you're trying to insert your variables into the *result* of your `print` call. `print(...)` returns `None`, so this won't work, and there's also the small matter of you already having printed your template by this time and time travel being prohibited by the laws of the universe we inhabit.

The whole thing you want to print, including the `%` and its operand, needs to be *inside* your `print(...)` call, so that the string can be built before it is printed.

```
print( "a=%d,b=%d" % (f(x,n), g(x,n)) )
```

I have added a few extra spaces to make it clearer (though they are not necessary and generally not considered good style).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that for a calculation, the parenthesis are necessary :

```py
>>> print( "%.2f" % 100*10.7/3309 )
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: cant multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
>>> print( "%.2f" % (100*10.7/3309) )
0.32
```

Answer (score -2):

`print("{:.4f} @\n".format(2))`

Formatting helpful in situations like these.

You can refer to further details in the link below.

[Python Formatting](https://pyformat.info/)