# printing timestamp values in a csv file

Tags: arrays, python-2.7, csv, printing, timestamp

I have a numpy array of time which is in seconds. I use the following code to convert seconds in to timestamp

```
m, s = divmod(seconds, 60)
h, m = divmod(m, 60)
for i in range(0, 24300):
   print h[i],":", m[i],":", s[i]
```

I need to print this timestamp values either in a csv file like( 01:05:25,01:04:60, 05:04:2) or store in a numpy array.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remembering that a CSV file is what it says, just comma separated values.

You've basically already got your answer.

You might want to delimit the times with quotation marks, some csv-parsers might assume that the values need to be text strings if they aren't just simple numbers.

Here's an example python code fragment

```
    import time
    import datetime
    from datetime import datetime

    for i in range(10):
        d = datetime.now()
        print('"{0}:{1}:{2}",'.format(d.hour,d.minute,d.second))
        time.sleep(1)
```

And this outputs the following times:

```
"12:30:40",
"12:30:41",
"12:30:42",
"12:30:43",
```

Comment: my doubt is how to concatenate integer with a string. I use                string= `h[i]` + ":" + `m[i]` + ":" + `s[i]`                                                             but it doesnt work.

Comment: Maybe have a look at this answer 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19457227/how-to-print-like-printf-in-python3