# Trouble printing out the result of a sum in python

Tags: string, python-3.x

I'm trying to print the result of an equation but it's giving me a syntax error, can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Here's the code:

```
num1 = 19
num2 = 35

print("hello the result of the sum is:" num1 + num2)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are missing a comma, checkout printing methods https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19457227/how-to-print-like-printf-in-python3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must separate with commas ( , ) each one of the values to print

```
num1 = 19 
num2 = 35
print("hello the result of the sum is:" , num1 + num2)
```