# I didn't find my erroe anywhere

Tags: python, csv, error-handling

Hi can someone please tell me why i have an invalid syntax that appear in the last line exactly in the second "
this is a script that iterates through the CSV file and converts everything to the decimal ASCII equivalent. Thank you

```
import csv
with open('C:\Users\user\Desktop\log_transformed_truncated.csv', 'w') as outfile:
c = csv.writer(outfile)
counter = 0
with open('C:\Users\user\Desktop\log.csv','rb') as f:
    for row in csv.reader(f, delimiter=';'):
        counter = counter + 1
        mod_row = []
        if counter != 1:
            for cell in row:
                mod_row.append(sum(bytearray(cell)))
        else:
            for cell in row:
                mod_row.append(cell)
        c.writerow(mod_row)
print "processed {} rows".format(counter)
```

Comment: Indentation error?

Comment: Is this python 2 or 3?

Comment: Can you post the entire error message?

Comment: The entire block under the upper `with`, starting at `c = csv.writer(outfile)` should be indented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to put parentheses as it is the syntax for python 3.

This statement works for me:

```
print("processed {} rows".format(counter))
```

You can also review this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19457247/8752338) for more information about the differences between the print statement in python 2 and python 3.

Comment: ...assuming questioner is using python 3.

Comment: If you run the line `print "processed {} rows".format(counter)` in a python 3 IDE you will get an expected syntax error at the second `"`, like the one the questioner referred to, making me believe he's using python 3. @tdelaney