# Two ways to use print function. Does it matter which is used?

Tags: python

This is a very simple question, but I am a new Python learner and this is bugging me.

I am using Python version 3.7.4. I want to know if it matters which way below I should use the print function or is one way more appropriate to use under some select circumstance.

```
print(f"Miles Per Gallon:\t\t {mpg}")
```

vs

```
print("Miles Per Gallon: \t\t " + str(mpg))
```

Comment: In practice, no, although the first should perform marginally better it should not make much of a difference.

Answer (score 2):

The first option (formatting) is much easier to read and write. For example instead of writing:

```py
print('He had ' + str(cookies) + ' cookies and ' str(bananas) + ' bananas')
```

You can simply write

```py
print(f'He had {cookies} cookies and {bananas} bananas.')
```

doing it that way you also avoid having to explicitly call `str`, as format does that for you. You can also use formatting like this:

```py
print('I have {} cookies'.format(cookies))
```

Comment: look here for further examples https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: there's no difference between the two.

In the first example you provided (`print(f"Miles Per Gallon:\t\t {mpg}")`), you're doing something in Python called formatting. It's a pretty useful concept that can come in handy when you want to put lots of things in one string without having to concatenate all of them.

In your second example, `print("Miles Per Gallon: \t\t " + str(mpg))`, instead of using formatting, you're converting `mpg` to a `string`, and then telling python to "concatenate" (merge) the two (the string to the left and the string to the right) together. `+` in Python will both concatenate and add numbers, depending on the types of the variables surrounding it.

Formatting in Python becomes very useful when you need to put a lot of things in one string. For example, let's say I want to print the value of 3 variables, `a`, `b`, and `c`, and I want to label them. For the sake of example, we'll say that we *don't know* if the variables are type `int` or `str`; this is important, because it means we need to explicitly convert them to a string, otherwise we run the risk of Python throwing a TypeError (specifically, `TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str`). To do this with concatenation (as your second example does), this is what would be done:

```
"The value of a is " + str(a) + ", b is " + str(b) + ", c is " + str(c)
```

As you can see, that can be kind of messy, which is where formatting comes in to play. There are lots of ways to format strings in Python. I'll use [yours](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#formatted-string-literals) in addition to [another common one](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format), but it's entirely personal preference which you would like to use.

```
f"The value of a is {a}, b is {b}, c is {c}"
"The value of a is {0}, b is {1}, c is {2}".format(str(a), str(b), str(c))
```

This is a lot cleaner, and makes for more easily readable code than concatenation, as well as making editing it less of a headache. More info on various ways of formatting string is available in the documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#fancier-output-formatting).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you so much!!  That explained it perfectly.  I really appreciate it!

Comment: Glad it was helpful!

Answer (score -1):

The second one has an explicit casting  str(), but the first one has an implicit casting. It depends when you will need an explicit casting.
You can also take a look at this question: [How to print like printf in Python3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19457227/how-to-print-like-printf-in-python3)

Comment: Hey buddy, welcome to stackoverflow. I guess you got downvoted because link-only answers are frowned upon here, it is always better to include examples in the answer itself instead of just linking to an off-site resource.

Comment: Thanks)) Yes it was surprising)