# Python: How can I replace multiple occurrences of a string with values in tuple

Tags: python

I have a string such as:
`"Hello %s, how are %s, %s"`

I need to replace all occurrences of `%s` with the elements of the tuple `("world", "you", 1)` in order for the output to be:

```
Hello world, how are you, 1
```

Comment: `"Hello %s, how are %s, %s" % ("world", "you", 1)`? See e.g. https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#printf-style-string-formatting.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to print like printf in Python3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19457227/how-to-print-like-printf-in-python3)

Comment: Hey @Gaurav Sharma would you like to replace string occurences or merely print using format()?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [String formatting: % vs. .format vs. string literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082452/string-formatting-vs-format-vs-string-literal)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`.format()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) method:

```
print("Hello {0}, how are {1}, {2}".format(*("world", "you", 1)))
```

The star `*` allows you to unpack the tuple so the `.format()` function can elaborate them.

Look [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-examples) for more examples.

In case you don't want to use the `.format()`, take a look at this:

```
print("Hello %s, how are %s, %s" % (("world", "you", 1)))
```

Both method will output:

```
Hello world, how are you, 1
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this:

```
def tupleFormat(string, format):
    return string % format
```

and then you could do yout example like:

```
tupleFormat("Hello %s, how are %s, %s", ("world", "you", 1))
```

You can use the % operator on strings and tuples, exactly how you want it.

Answer (score 1):

If your aim is to replace string occurrences, you could try the following:

```
string = 'Hello %s, how are %s, %s'
tupl = ('world', 'you', '1')

for t in tupl:
  string = string.replace('%s', t, 1)

print(string)
```

Output:

```
Hello world, how are you, 1
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple answer:

```
print("Hello %s, how are %s, %s" % ("world", "you", 1))
```

Output:

```
Hello world, how are you, 1
```