# How do I get rid of whitespace before punctuation?

Tags: python

I'm doing a project for school and I'm having some issues trying to get this white space out of it. Keep in mind I'm very much a beginner at all of this.
It goes as follows:

```
print('What is your name?')
user_name = input()
print('How old are you?')
user_age = int(input())
birth_year = (2023 - user_age)
print('Hello',user_name,"!",'You were born in',birth_year,".")
```

Everything but the last line works perfectly, because once it runs everything and goes to print this, I get something that looks like this:

```
Hello e ! You were born in 2011 .
```

Is there any way I could fix the code to get rid of this whitespace? It's driving me crazy.
Thanks in advance.

I did try to change things around by getting rid of commas and adding `+` signs and tampering with it anyway I could and I only got syntax errors.

Comment: Maybe this will make things clear: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19457227/how-to-print-like-printf-in-python3

Comment: Construct the single string you want to print yourself, instead of letting `print` assemble the string from multiple arguments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this:

```
print('Hello',user_name,"!",'You were born in',birth_year,".")
```

with the following:

```
print('Hello %s! You were born in %d.' % (user_name, birth_year))
```

Comment: Ohhhhh my gosh thank you. I've been suck on this a hot minute, I appreciate this so much!

Comment: `f'Hello {user_name}! You were born in {birth year}.'` would be more commonly recommended nowadays. The `%` operator is quite old and has relatively few advantages over f-strings.